# Which puppet module should I include for a managed database mysql::client using netmanagers/bareos?

Tags: puppet, bareos

When I include the following in my `nodes.pp`:

```
 class {'bareos':
      ...
       manage_database => true,
      ...
```

I get the following error:

```
==> bareOSdirector: Error: Could not find class mysql::client for bareosdirector on node bareosdirector
==> bareOSdirector: Error: Could not find class mysql::client for bareosdirector on node bareosdirector
```

There seem to be quite a few mysql modules out there, does anyone have an idea of which one was intended to be a dependency of this library?

I'm aware that [netmanagers bareos](https://forge.puppet.com/netmanagers/bareos/compatibility) is unmaintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would start using a dependency manager such as R10K or Librarian-Puppet to keep track of your modules and install whatever dependencies necessary for your modules to run.

To use your module in `librarian-puppet`, all you would need to do is add the following line to your `Puppetfile`:

```
mod 'netmanagers/bareos'
```

and let `librarian-puppet` handle resolving and installing dependencies for both that specific module and all of the others throughout the chain (e.g. the dependencies of `example42/monitor`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you fulfilled all dependencies (puppetlabs/stdlib, example42/puppi, example42/firewall and example42/monitor)?

AFAIK netmanagers/bareos is based on a netmanagers/puppet-bacula module which requires "Puppetlabs/mysql" (see https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/mysql)